# Insert with self generated primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to perform an `INSERT` using a `SELECT` to generate a primary key

**Table** Employee:

```
ID(PK)   NAME
1        John
2        Doo
3        James
```

**Table** Friends:

```
ID(PK)   FriendName
```

Now I want to insert all Employees into the Friends and self generate the PK.

I tried:

```
INSERT INTO Friends (ID, FriendName) 
   SELECT  (SELECT max(ID)+1 FROM Friends) as ID
           , Name as FriendName 
   FROM    Employee
```

For the first record that works fine. Then I get a duplicate key error from MySQL.

How I can do this `(Select max(ID)+1 from Friends)` once per row? If that is not the correct approach, how should I structure my `INSERT` statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you want a key that is always incrementing check [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Then  you can do the insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO Friends (FriendName)
select Name as FriendName FROM Employee
```